# Updating a published color scheme on Package Control

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, package-control

I have a color scheme published on Package Control. I've made some changes to it in its Git repository, and I've updated its tag version and pushed the tags. However, the version on Package Control isn't updating, and it has been quite awhile now. Does it just normally take awhile or did I do something wrong?

Comment: > Package Control will check it for updates approximately once per hour. The *Last Seen* date on the package detail page of this site will show the last time (UTC) when the package information was refreshed. Maybe it is easier to help if you provide a link to the github repo and the package control

Comment: @Peh, thanks. It's been updated so now so I guess I just needed to wait longer. Why don't you post this comment as an answer just in case other people ask the same question.

Comment: Hah, didn't think that this would answer the question already. I just wanted to hint out that there is a *Last Seen* date. But I added it so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should update automatically:

> Package Control will check it for updates approximately once per hour. The Last Seen date on the package detail page of this site will show the last time (UTC) when the package information was refreshed.

from https://packagecontrol.io/docs/submitting_a_package#Step_3